# React input doesn't type

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use React Bootstrap Form but I couldn't tape into the input and I deciced to try with the classic default one but it doesn't work as well(just if I paste something in). In the sandbox works perfectly but when I copy it in my page it doesn't.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react"

const StandAdd = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("")

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setTest(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + test)
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={test} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}

export default StandAdd
```

Sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-vb2o1?file=/src/App.js

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have used in your real application?

Comment: The `CodeSandbox` example works just fine - impossible to help without knowing what's going on in your actual app. Perhaps you're missing those `onChange` handlers from some of your input fields in your actual code.

Comment: Everything looks fine in the sample, standard approach would be restarting your app and if that doesnt help delete node_modules and reinstall whole thing.

Comment: I updated with the entire page

Comment: Is this your component exactly? Because it does work just fine, although you don't need the `event.preventDefault()` in the `handleChange` event handler.

Comment: I created a pge page with a working form and I paste it in. Now works! I dunno how. but I'm tring to use the Form from boostrap but is still doens't

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing exactly what you're doing. All the code snippets you've provided work just fine, edit your `CodeSandbox` example and add the bootstrap form - you can include dependencies there.

Answer (score 1):

## Your state is undefined and there for uncontrolled

You just need a default value as part of your state.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState('');
```

This happens because your initial value of `test` is `undefined`. This is the same as removing that prop. So you need to make sure the value is at least an empty string.

Comment: Although the default value is missing, it still works and it's not preventing you from typing things into the input field, which is what OP seems to be having issues with.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. the example has none and works